# Default value for subscript [] operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, default, operator-keyword

I'd like to have a PHP style push_back feature for an array class of mine :

```
arrayT<int> arr;
arr[] = 10; // == std::vector::push_back()
```

and

```
arrayT::operator[]( size_t pos = (size_t)-1)
```

Is this possible ?
If yes is it also possible with some other operators ?

Comment: Even if it was possible, this would be very confusing and non-idiomatic. Use a separate method, it's saner.

Comment: Why would it be confusing ?

Comment: @Virus721 Because programmers like syntax they are comfortable with seeing and using. This would not be comfortable at all. If I was reading some C++ code and saw that, I would think "What kind of devilish hack is going on here?" I'd have to read the documentation to figure out what it was doing. If it was a function called `push_back`, however, I'd understand immediately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> An operator function cannot have default arguments (8.3.6), except where explicitly stated below.

> `operator[]` shall be a non-static member function with exactly one parameter.

The only operator function that is allowed to have default arguments is `operator()`. And you can't declare `operator[]` to take no arguments.

So no, what you ask for is not possible.

Comment: You can't even overload it to take no arguments, if memory serves.

Comment: You can wrap it around a function that forward a default value thereto.